# Hide API URL in android application - 2018

Tags: java, android

After reading several topics about this, I tried to put my API URL in gradle as BuildConfigField, but when I decompile it, I was able to see.

Is there any current way to hide it now?

Answer (score 0):

Use a secret manager service as [Hashicorp Vault](https://www.hashicorp.com/products/vault/secrets-management) or [AWS Secret manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/)

**From AWS Secret manager page:**

> The service enables you to easily rotate, manage, and retrieve database credentials, API keys, and other secrets throughout their lifecycle. Users and applications retrieve secrets with a call to Secrets Manager APIs, eliminating the need to hardcode sensitive information in plain text

I'm facing the same problem as you now and it looks to be the solution for my use case.